# Is it possible to define a continuous field with characteristic $\neq 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

For example, defining an addition and multiplication on the unit circle in the complex plane such that it forms a field.

This would be a sort of continuous analog of the finite fields. Another way I thought you might construct this is by defining modular equivalence classes on the real numbers by modding the whole part of the number. Does such a "continuous finite field" exist? If not, why can't one exist?

Comment: If you just want the continuum cardinality, as sdcvvc has said, $\mathbb{F}_p(\{x_i\})$ does the trick for a set of countable variables $\{x_i\}$.

Comment: Regarding the structure of continuous field on the unit circle you can see http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter5.pdf .